# Is it possible to update Observable with own data in Angular2 / Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an ngFor with async like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let location of googleSearchLocations | async">
<div *ngFor="let location of facebookSearchLocations | async">
```

and this is my component:

```
private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
googleSearchLocations: Observable<GoogleLocation[]>;
facebookSearchLocations: Observable<FacebookLocation[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.googleSearchLocations = this.searchTerms
                                     .debounceTime(300)
                                     .switchMap(term => term 
                                         ? this.locationService.getGoogleLocations(term)
                                         : Observable.of<GoogleLocation[]>([]));

    this.facebookSearchLocations = this.searchTerms
                                       .debounceTime(300)
                                       .switchMap(term => term
                                           ? this.locationService.getFacebookLocations(term)
                                           : Observable.of<FacebookLocation[]>([]));
}

search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
}
```

To populate both arrays I use `search` method with a value from the input.

Now at some point I wanted to hide the divs by just assigning an empty array which will hide the data (like in non-async case). But it appeared to be more complex than I thought, since assigning null or new Observable breaks future updates. So is there a way to somehow do "next" or send some data to observable directly (an empty array in my case)?

I know I can just push it to the `searchTerms`, but is not desired since it will hide both divs at the same time + it will use the debounce value.

Comment: Why you can't make just `searchTerms.next(null)`?

Comment: I have two observable dependent on it (2 popups in UI), and I want to close only one of them when a user clicks there.

Comment: Another thing is that I have e.g. debounce there, but I want the popup to be closed immediately.

Comment: Provide entire code samples for what you really want. The answer from Martin fixes what you are trying to do as described in your question.

Comment: I have updated the question and the provided solution is unfortunately not enough since it will use the debounce and hide two divs at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following. You keep your code but merge the subject into it. This would look like this:

```
let subject = new Subject();

this.googleSearchLocations = this.searchTerms
                                 .debounceTime(300)
                                 .switchMap(term => term 
                                     ? this.locationService.getGoogleLocations(term)
                                     : Observable.of<GoogleLocation[]>([]))
                                 .merge(subject);
```

If you know want to clear the list. You could just do

```
subject.next([]);
```

This doesn't mess with the original searchTerms stream and allows you to clear the result immediately and only for one of the two.

You can provide two different subject for the two (google and facebook) so you could clear them both separately at your time of choosing.

Jsbin with a similar example can be found here: http://jsbin.com/pagilab/edit?js,console

It first emulates result being found and clears the result with an empty array after 2seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did not know you can add additional subjects to Observable. It should do the trick. I am also wondering if it's possible to base some ngIf's on the Observable data (e.g. if I want to have a div that wraps my ngFor's)