# How to use observable in ngFor (async pipe) when the element is hidden in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following html template:

```
<div *ngIf="googleSearchVisible">
    <div *ngFor="let location of googleSearchLocations | async"> </div>
</div>
```

Now when I begin pushing data to observable nothing happens. I do believe this happens because the element does not subscribe to observable.

I have tried to add `googleSearchLocations.subscribe` during `onInit` and this does force a call to a service and even makes ngIf visible, but ngFor is still not rendering anything.

How can I enforce the observable this way?

P.S. `googleSearchVisible` turns on in the `.do` when I load data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to update Observable with own data in Angular2 / Typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260197/is-it-possible-to-update-observable-with-own-data-in-angular2-typescript)

Comment: It's not duplicate, it's a separate question on it's own about how observables behave under ngIf. It can be used to solve the problem in the question you mention, so they are related in a way, but not a duplicate at all in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that it does work fine with `hidden`

```
<div [hidden]="!googleSearchVisible">
    <div *ngFor="let location of googleSearchLocations | async"> </div>
</div>
```

This does not explain though why nothing is rendered even with `subscribe`.

Found a related issue on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9641). It seems there is bug in angular.